Construct a cone from independently sampled surface points
2 points are sufficient to determine a 3D line, 3 points are sufficient to determine a 3D plane and there are well-known formulas to construct lines and planes from such points.
I understand that there is no such minimum number of points to uniquely determine a circular cone due to degenerate cases, e.g. 4 or more points are co-planar or 3 or more points are co-linear. If all points where co-planar or co-linear not even an infinite number of them would be enough.
So let's assume we have a well-behaved sets of $n$ points (no co-planar, no co-linear) that were independently and uniformly sampled from the surface of a given circular cone.
Is there a constructive proof that:

recovers the original circular cone from $n$ surface points and
shows $n$ is the minimum number of points that we need to use?

Or is there a negative proof instead?

To get a suitable answer you will need to specify what kind of cone you are talking about. I'm guessing you mean what is called a "circular cone" on this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cone but it would be better to state this clearly.

@Quadrics can you provide a constructive proof that shows that 4 is the minimum number?

A cone is quadric. For a generic quadric, nine points are needed to fix it. But a cone has a constraint, hence eight points should be enough.

A point $P=(x,y,z)$ belongs to the surface of a cone with vertex $V=(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ if vector $P-V$ forms a fixed angle $\theta$ with the direction $\vec a=(x_a,y_a,z_a)$ of the axis.
Hence the equation of the cone can be written as:
$$
{(P-V)\cdot\vec a\over|P-V|\ |\vec a|}=\cos\theta
$$
and it depends on seven constants: the six coordinates of $P$ and $\vec a$ and angle $\theta$.
The equation can be rewritten as
$$
{(x-x_0)x_a+(y-y_0)y_a+(z-z_0)z_a
\over  \sqrt{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2+(z-z_0)^2}\sqrt{x_a^2+y_a^2+z_a^a}}=
{\cos\theta}.
$$
In principle then, given seven points on the cone, we can plug their coordinates in the above equation and solve the system of seven equations to find the seven unknown parameters.
EDIT.
I've found a fault in the above discussion: the length of $\vec a$ is irrelevant and can be set to $1$. Hence there are only six parameters in the equation and six points should be enough to find the cone.
EDIT 2.
I put to test the above procedure and found that multiple solutions are possible. Here's the details.
I constructed with GeoGebra a cone with:
$$
V=(0,0,2),\quad 
\vec a=(0,0,-1),\quad
\cos\theta=2/\sqrt5\approx0.894427.
$$
I chose six points at random on that cone:
$$
\begin{align}
&A = (-0.18926, -0.4628, 1), \quad
&&B = (0.44543, -0.40142, 0.80077)\\
&C = (0.40807, -0.05279, 1.17706)\quad
&&D = (-0.06686, -0.88892, 0.21715)\\
&E = (0.53033, 0.53033, 0.5)\quad
&&F = (-0.69158, 0.4221, 0.37957)
\end{align}
$$
and submitted to the numerical solver of Mathematica the system formed by six equations of the cone with $(x,y,z)$ replaced by the coordinates of the six points, plus a seventh equation: $x_a^2+y_a^2+z_a^a=1$. Here are the four different results I got.
First solution:
$$
\begin{align}
V&=(2.01633, 0.905797, 1.58297),\\
\vec a&=(-0.818043, -0.387263, -0.425244),\\
\cos\theta&=0.970611.
\end{align}
$$
Second solution:
$$
\begin{align}
V&=(0.0000149355, -0.0000299256, 1.99995),\\ 
\vec a&=(-7.01324\cdot10^{-6}, 0.0000136325, -1.),\\
\cos\theta&=0.894421.
\end{align}
$$
Third solution:
$$
\begin{align}
V&=(0.316438, -1.49605, 0.018405),\\
\vec a&=(-0.197804, 0.894372, 0.401213),\\
\cos\theta&=0.937661.
\end{align}
$$
Fourth solution:
$$
\begin{align}
V&=(41.2335, 71.5513, 122.117),\\
\vec a&=(0.280394, -0.486399, -0.827523),\\
\cos\theta&=0.999988.
\end{align}
$$
As you can see, the second solution is the original cone, but the other ones are also good and give three more possible cones.

Do you say "in principle" because in practice we have to rely on numerical methods to solve such system of non linear equations right?

@FrancescoSolera Yes, in practice solving that system could be quite difficult. BTW: in a comment above I wrote that eight points were needed, but I hadn't considered that we are dealing here with a circular cone. That gives another constraint and lowers the number of points to seven.

@Quadrics There is no guarantee, here's a counterexample, obtained taking six points on the surface of a cylinder: $$(1, 0, 0), (-1/2, \sqrt3/2, 0), (-1/2, -\sqrt3/2, 0), (0, 1, 1), (\sqrt3/2, -1/2, 1), (-\sqrt3/2, -1/2, 1)$$ With Mathematica I get 14 double cones containing all those points, but in no case all the points lie on the same nappe.

@Quadrics I didn't know the name either, loked it up on Wikipedia: "Either half of a double cone on one side of the apex is called a nappe." Moreover, the double cones I found are only 7: for technical reasons I got each solution twice.

@Quadrics What's wrong with my counterexample above?

My answer above, and the question, are about a SINGLE cone, not a double cone. I think you should ask a new question.

@Intelligentipauca: why do you say the question is about a "single" cone? I don't see that stipulation written anywhere.

@LazzaroCampeotti Well, my answer is clearly about a single cone, and it was accepted. But you are right: the OP was not clear about that. Anyway, for a double cone one just needs to square both sides of my equation.
